# Количество элементов в таблице

Tags: python

Как наибыстрейшим способом определить количество элементов в таблице? Я делаю так:

```
u_count = len(User.objects.all().distinct())
```

Запросы делаю еще по 4 таблицам, выполняется дико долго. Возможно ли оптимизировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
u_count = User.objects.all().distinct().count()
```